# Flutter better_player cannot play video url without extension

Tags: android, flutter, video-streaming, exoplayer, android-video-player

this is a video url:

```
https://d6b09034.tekurarere.tk/mq/NNUVmAXzjPHmdFAxvlmOAXjNYAmNAgjVmZJiRmX_lp
```

**My code:**

```
@override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
        "https://d6b09034.tekurarere.tk/mq/NNUVmAXzjPHmdFAxvlmOAXjNYAmNAgjVmZJiRmX_lp",
        headers: {"User-Agent:":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0", "Content-Type:":"application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"}
        );
    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
        BetterPlayerConfiguration(),
        betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource);
  }
```

**Expected behavior:**
play a video from a url without file extension

**Flutter doctor**

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.168, on Linux, locale tr_TR.utf8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)

**Better Player version:**
^0.0.48

**Scrensshots:**

can be played url (vlc, js video player bla bla )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bOI8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in 0.0.49

New - - > videoFormat options

```dart
BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
        "https://d6b09034.tekurarere.tk/mi/NNUVmAXzjPHmdFAxvlmOAXjNYAmNAgjVmZJiRmX_lp",
        videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.hls,
        headers: {
          "User-Agent:":
              "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0",
          "Content-Type:": "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"
        });
```